# How to write an alphanumeric file parser?

Tags: c++, parsing

I have the following code so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ofstream outfile;
    ifstream infile;
    string line;

    infile.open ("input.DAT");
    outfile.open ("output.txt");

    while (infile.good()){
        getline (infile, line);
        outfile << line << endl;
    }

    outfile.close();
    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

All this does is take what it's input.DAT and output it to output.txt. The input file is not clean, though. It's in this type of format:

> *(ASCII GARBAGE)* 1:66 OS WARSAW, POLAND *(ASCII GARBAGE)*

Example pic:

[image]

---

Another example:

[image]

---

So what I want to do is output the stuff between the garbage, newline delimited. But I don't know how to iterate/output by character and what a good way is to dictate what's a valid output (I mean I could check if the character is within a particular range I suppose but I don't know how this is done in C++).

I think what may help is to start by searching for something in the form of (Number)(Number)(Colon)(Number)(Space) or (Number)(Colon)(Number)(Space) and then taking everything up until something that isn't a letter/comma/period/etc, and adding a newline. Can this be done?

I hope this makes sense! Let me know if I need to clarify more.

EDIT: First attempt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ofstream outfile;
    ifstream infile;
    string line, res;

    infile.open ("input.DAT");
    outfile.open ("output.txt");

    while (infile.good()){
        std::getline(infile, line);

        res = "";
        for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < line.length()-4; i++){
            if (isdigit(line[i+1]) && line[i+2]==":" && isdigit(line[i+3])){
                res+=line[i];
                i++;
                while (isalnum(line[i]) || line[i] == "/" || line[i] == "\\" || line[i] == "=" || line[i] == "#" || line[i] == ":" || line[i] == " " || line[i] == "." || line[i] == "," || line[i] == "-" || line[i] == "'" || line[i] == '"'){
                    res+=line[i];
                    i++;
                }
                outfile << res << endl;
                res = "";
            }  
        }


    }

    outfile.close();
    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

It does not compile though because "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer "

edit: Fixed this myself, changed the quotes to single-quotes. I think I figured out my own problem here. It won't let me delete my question though.

Comment: So what _IS_ valid input and what isn't? "ASCII garbage" means what?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I added a few examples to the OP

Comment: @AgainstASicilian instead of reading it in line by line I would recommend my solution reading it in one character at a time.

Comment: You should ask a more specific question, or split this "fix my program" question into several.

Answer (score 3):

I will leave it up to you to decide what is garbage and what is not. Here is an example of how you can remove all symbols you don't like from every line before writing it to another file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

static bool is_garbage(char c)
{
    return !isalnum(c); // This is my perception on garbage. Yours might be different.
}

int main()
{
    std::ofstream outfile;
    std::ifstream infile;
    std::string line;

    infile.open("input.DAT");
    outfile.open("output.txt");

    while (infile.good()) {
        std::getline(infile, line);
        line.erase(std::remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), is_garbage),
                   line.end());
        outfile << line << std::endl;
    }

    outfile.close();
    infile.close();
}
```

The above code removes everything that is not an alphabetic character. And here are some references that explain each function in more details:

- [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)
- [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
- [isalnum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum)

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: I think what may help is to start by searching for something in the form of (Number)(Number)(Colon)(Number)(Space) or (Number)(Colon)(Number)(Space) and then taking everything up until something that isn't a letter/comma/period/etc, and adding a newline. Can this be done?

Comment: @AgainstASicilian: It sure can, but how is that better than just removing non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: The resulting output is basically a huge single string of letters/numbers when I do something like that, and not all letters/numbers are necessarily valid.

Comment: @AgainstASicilian: Well, I can't really tell you what to do, but surely you can go differently about this — use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), or even regular expressions (i.e. [`std::regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace)). If that possible to determine the format of your input, that would probably be the best. I bet it is some format, not a random garbage.

Comment: How can I iterate until I come across characters that fit this template and then output everything up until something isn't a character/space/period/colon/etc?

Comment: @AgainstASicilian: Use std::string's begin/end, or `at()` methods. Start by reading [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) documentation...

Comment: I've looked through the documentation but I wouldn't have made this question if I were able to figure it out. I don't know the proper way to take in the data/iterate the characters/see if it matches some template/output by character up until some condition/etc.

Comment: @AgainstASicilian: I showed you how to iterate — use begin/end. How to write a parser depends on what and how you want to parse. Given a very vague nature of your input and its format and a huge uncertainty in what you want to do, I can't really help you much. Come up with an algorithm first, then ask how to implement it, perhaps in a different question. I reset my case!

Comment: In all honesty I think my question is pretty clear

Comment: I added some sample code in the OP

Answer (score 1):

So, a function like this:

```
#include <cctype>

std::string clean_string(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string res;
    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
       if (std::isprint(str[i])
          res += str[i];
    }
    return res;
 }
```

Comment: Chances are that `unsigned int` might not be enough to store `std::string::size_type`. This also creates an extra copy of the string for no good reason.

Comment: Yes, of course. But it's relatively simple to understand what it does, and none of the examples given show strings that are more than about 60 bytes long, so worrying about strings that are at least 64KB (and probably 4GB) is a little unreasonable.

Comment: Yeah I never saw an 8GB string in my life :)

Comment: No, I don't think I have either. I have seen code behaving badly from being given symbols from a symbol file where the templated mangled symbol was about 9KB, and apparently the code had decided that around 1KB was "quite suffiicent" for the strings - and no checking either, it just overflowed the stack and crashed when trying to return to "four bytes picked out of the symbol name".

Comment: Can't one just use a size_t?

Comment: Yes, size_t should work, although technically you should use `std::string::size_type`. I was just being slightly lazy/simplistic. For the examples you have given, it won't make a difference unless the size is larger than the maximum value of unsigned - for Windows and Linux that is 4GB. So if your line of text is like in your example, it certainly won't make a difference.

Comment: As I have amended it now.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I added more to the OP

Comment: Your error is because you are comparing `"x"` with a type `char` - use `'x'` instead.